# "Просто" — сказуемое

Tags: сказуемые, синтаксический-разбор

Помогите разобрать предложение:
**Ему просто туда попасть, достаточно перелезть через забор.**

В "Викисловаре" утверждается, что в этом предложении это слово — сказуемое, но не могу понять, как его выявили.
Тогда "попасть" — дополнение (просто — что? — ему)?

Answer (score 4):

*"Ему просто туда попасть..."*

Подлежащее - инфинитив "попасть". Попасть - (это каково?) просто (то есть простое дело). Просто - сказуемое.